# Selecting and printing specific lines from a non rectangular text file (In MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, select, printing, row, text-files

Hopefully somebody can help me as I am about to finish a program but I am having trouble with the format that my text file has.

My text file is quite large. I paste here the first 9 lines (Note that is a non rectangular text file which contains numeric and string data):

```
AFH,98.3,76.4,D,2,56.3,H

TYU,65.2,K,47,I

UJK,67.5,J

AFH,65.5,56.5,L,8,34.1,P

TYU,56.2,S,97,T

UJK,88.5,J

AFH,32.1,11.4,G,4,45.6,F

TYU,22.8,D,37,U

UJK,78.3,Z
```

The only data that I need from the entire text file are the lines that start with 'AFH'. I need to manage reading just these specific lines and write them in a new text file, so that I can use this last text file as input to run the rest of my program.

I can't find any way to be able to select just my 'AFH' lines to print them in a new text file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is read the file line by line using `fgetl` and ignore the irrelevant lines.

```
myText = cell(1,N);

tline = fgetl(fid);                % Read first line
while ischar(tline)                % Keep going til the end of the file
    if strcmp(tline(1:3),'AFH')    % Check if it starts with 'AFH'
        myText{end+1} = tline;     % Save the line in cell array  
    end
    tline = fgetl(fid);            % Read the next line
end
```

Comment: I have been trying your code but I keep getting an empty cell array:-(